# Summary a list of integers into two columns in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, integer, names

This is what I've got (a list):

```
>head(indexes)
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 13

[[4]]
[1] 2 3

[[5]]
[1] 25

[[6]]
[1] 26

> all(vapply(indexes, is.numeric, TRUE)) # (note that..)
[1] TRUE
```

.. and this is what I want (same information for me):

```
>head(res,6)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   12
[2,]    3   13
[3,]    4    2
[4,]    4    3
[5,]    5   25
[6,]    6   36
```

Is there a clever way to do this?

I tried a trick with naming the list:

```
names(indexes) <- 1:lenght(indexes)
res <- c(indexes, recursive=TRUE)
res <- cbind(as.integer(names(res)), res)
```

But R (such a kind damn kid!) breaks everything down by renaming the identical rows in an ambiguous fashion:

```
>head(res)
      res
2   2   2
3   3   3
41 41   2
42 42   3
5   5   5
6   6   6

# ... (think about what happens around lines 3675.. 41158..)
```

.. if this was the clever way, how do I prevent the renaming?

Comment: `cbind(rep(seq(idx), sapply(idx, length)), unlist(idx))`  (but not clever)

Comment: @user20650 Why not clever? ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wops! Okay, nailed it:

```
res <- cbind(
  rep(1:length(indexes), vapply(indexes,length,1)),
   c(indexes,recursive=TRUE)
)
```

.. just tell me if anyone found a better way, then :)